# Display template for content search webpart issue for datatable and Tabs

Tags: sharepoint-2013, display-templates

I have developed display template and using it in Content search web part.

For displaying result on page i am using JQuery datatable/JQuery Tabs in display template.

Everything works fine, but sometime while loading page i am getting error like `("Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable' (OnPostRender: )`" and for tabs error is  "Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs' `(OnPostRender: )")`.

And if i refresh page many times then error will go and result is display as code.

I have register JQuery, JS and CSS using  `$includeScript.`

I have also tried with RegisterSod for JQuery and JS file but still issue is same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please, edit with your codes. 
Are you using IE?

Comment: yes, i am using IE

Comment: see my edit please

Answer (score 0):

Can be: 
This error usually occurs when an `html` element **id** has the **same id** as some variable in the javascript function, try change the name.

If you put the code I'll be able to help you **better**.

```
test = button.attr('test'); // Object doesnt support this method

$test= button.attr('test'); // works fine
```

Or debbug **your code** with and **discover your problem**. Enable script debugging IE:

- In Internet Explorer, choose Internet Options from the Tools menu.
- In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
- On the Advanced tab, under Browsing, clear Disable Script Debugging.
- Click OK.

If you have IE 8+ [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Tutorial Using jQuery dataTables: [link here](https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/using-jquery-datatables-with-search-display-templates/)